# How do I send a JavaScript confirm response over Django to a script to perform operations based on the response?

Tags: javascript, python, django, post, get

I'm very very new to Django and I'm currently trying to build a simple To-Do application. I'm currently able to display my To-Do list on the webpage using HTML Tables, but to be able to delete it, I added a new row at the end of every entry called `"Delete"` with an a `href element, on click event` sending it to a JS function that pops up a confirmation to the user asking if he actually wants to delete it. I'm storing the response in a variable called `response`. Now, my question is how do I send this response across django to actually be able to delete the entry? This is what I have done so far and its not working. All help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```
{% for item in task %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ item.task_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.task_priority }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.task_status }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.target_date }}</td>
    <td><a href="" onclick="return delete_function()">Delete</a></td>
        <p id="delete"></p>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </table>
<script>
    function delete_function() {
        var response = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
        if (response == true){
            response.post()
        }
    }
</script>
```

In my views page, I have this function to handle this post method:

```
def view_task(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        context = dict()
        context['task'] = Task.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'todo/view_tasks.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_name = request.post['task_name']
        Task.objects.delete(task_name)
        Task.objects.save()
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, could you also explain to me with your answer when and where should I use post and get or at least direct me to some very well answered questions about the same topic?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this would be a good way to solve the problem,

try to do this:

in your template.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="delete_amount" onclick="delete_me(event)" />
</form>
```

in your view.py:

```
#just in case you have other form
if 'delete_amount' in request.POST:
    # do your deleting query here
    print('deleting amount')
```

and in your javascript.js:

```
<script>
function delete_me(e)
{
     if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')){
          //prevent sending the request when user clicked 'Cancel'
          e.preventDefault();
     }
}

</script>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can put the form in your table column on each row.

Comment: Was a bit confused with the comment, but e.preventDefault() will prevent sending the request and you don't need additional code